# Get average from nested eloquent relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I would like to calculate average from nested relationship between eloquent models. So, let's say, I have 3 tables called `programs`, `activities` and `statistics`.

For simplicity sake, I will try to minimize the structure as follows:

`program` table:

```
-------------
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | Foo  |
| 2  | Bar  |
-------------
```

`activities` table:

```
-----------------------------------
| id | program_id | name          |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | Foo 1         |
| 2  | 1          | Foo 2         |
| 3  | 1          | Foo 3         |
| 4  | 2          | Bar 1         |
| 5  | 2          | Bar 2         |
-----------------------------------
```

`statistics` table:

```
-----------------------------------
| id | activity_id | type | score |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | 1           | A    | 25    |
| 2  | 1           | B    | 20    |
| 3  | 1           | A    | 22    |
| 4  | 2           | A    | 27    |
| 5  | 2           | B    | 24    |
| 6  | 3           | A    | 23    |
-----------------------------------
```

Now, what I want to get is the average of `score` of a `program` with specific `type` of `statistic`. I defined relationship in models, and tried following code, but no avail:

```
$program = Program::find(1);
$avg     = $program->activities->where('statistics.type', 'A')->avg('statistics.value');
```

$avg always 0 or null if there is no activities in program, even without `where` clause.

i'm sure that i defined the relationship correctly because `$program->activities` returns a sets of activities and `$activity-> statistics` return a sets of statistics as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) like this:

```
Statistics::whereHas('activity', function ($q) use($programId) {
        $q->where('program_id', $programId);
    })
    ->where('type', 'A')
    ->avg('score');
```

Make sure you've defined `activity` relationship which should be "statistics belongsTo() activity".

Comment: Oh it appear to be working, but since the actual code loop whole `program` in the view, I think i need to put it somewhere so i can call it in blade.. any ideas? oh and also, is it possible to get average for whole programs? (which mean i dont need specify program id but still specify the `type`)

Comment: @tonic you can put this into a controller, but it's so much better to put the logic into a model and run it from a controller to pass data to a view. Keeping data related logic in a view is a terrible idea. If you want to find an average for all programs wouldn't simple `Statistics::where('type', 'A')->avg('score')` work for you? If some statistics can have no a program and you want to get statistics which belongs to some activity only, use `has()`: `Statistics::has('activity')->where('type', 'A')->avg('score')`

Comment: Oh, nevermind for the second question, I just can directly use where clause straight to `statistics`, silly me haha